# connecting to TFS using windows auth in electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, tfs, electron

i'm building an electron app that connect to a TFS server and retrieve some data from it. 
They use Windows credential to access TFS , how can i connect to TFS using Windows credential through chrome or node.js ?

i tried this code but give me 401 : unauthorized

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'https://tfs.myserver.com:8090/tfs/IKM.TPC.Projects/MR/_workitems',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                }
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                    $('#result').text(data);
                })
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#result').text(textStatus);
                });
```

Comment: Using a valid REST API URL would probably help matters

Comment: I don't think you can using windows credential without the password. There are some package are not truly integrated since they require the user password, for example: https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm

Comment: i am using a valid url in the real app .. the url here is only for demonstration

Comment: Could you let user to provide the username and password?

Comment: yes , but for one time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple steps:

1. Create a login page to let user login with username and password
2. Store username and password in a variable, cookie or [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)
3. Send the request by using [httpntml](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm) with username, password, domain